# Dump database table or work remotely for analysis?

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, data-analysis

I have a table of **80 million** rows and I was given the task to do some light analysis like finding patterns for fields, which fields are mutually exclusive etc.

My initial instinct was to dump the whole table into a CSV so I can work with Pandas or similar since I assumed it would be faster and easier to work with. While figuring out ways on how to get the whole table into a CSV, a colleague insisted that it is overkill and the conventional approach is to work directly with the Oracle database.

From my software background, my understanding has been that databases are more for keeping the state of big applications and less for a human to fiddle with. What is the common approach for analysis when having such big tables? What is faster? Personally I don't mind the time it takes to dump the database but more about the time it takes to get back feedback when doing the actual analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Directly on the database with SQL is perfectly fine for any analysis *when you already know what you're looking for*.

When you don't know what you're looking for, and you want to do e.g. pattern recognition, the effort to dump and process in another tool is probably worth it.

Also consider the possibility to connect Pandas directly to your Oracle database (which allows you to skip dumping data), [see here for an example](http://dominicgiles.com/blog/files/bbffdb638932620b3182980fbd0e3d5b-146.html).